# How does the @ work in Bash?

Tags: bash

When I open BashBurn source I se:

```
mainmenu[7]="$bb_menu_8@check_path"
```

I don't know what does `@check_path` mean? And how does it work?

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski i think that, too. But when i run program it only display value of $bb_menu_8.

Comment: *`bash`* doesn't do *anything*; it's just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't mean any special in Bash alone: `@` is just a part of a string here. It could have a special meaning inside the BashBurn implementation, however.

It looks like it is a part of the translation framework used inside BashBurn. You can search it on your own on [GitHub for example](https://github.com/aelinden/BashBurn/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=check_path&type=Code).

`mainmenu` is set in [`BashBurn.sh`](https://github.com/aelinden/BashBurn/blob/15c930a423ee9ce6b6a8099771bfc7b133070c00/playground/filemanager/BashBurn.sh), which is then passed as the second argument to the `bbmenu` function. The function is defined in [`bbmenu.sh`](https://github.com/aelinden/BashBurn/blob/15c930a423ee9ce6b6a8099771bfc7b133070c00/releases/3.0-beta1/menus/bbmenu.sh). There is a description of the syntax, including this information:

> ALL ITEMS ARE SEPERATED BY AMPERSAND.

All you need to do now is to read the rest of the documentation in the `bbmenu.sh` file.

Comment: can you help me explain how does it work? It translation $bb_menu_8 to other language?

Comment: @tuấnanhnguyễnhữu I've got no idea how this works. Try on your own and ask specific questions on Stack Overflow or Unix SE if you're stuck.